# Is there a similar function to tf.image.adjust_contrast in TFJS?

Tags: reactjs, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

While I was using this step for pre-processing my data when training my model, I do not see the option to use this step in TFJS. I tried searching online and even tried doing `tf.image.adjust_contrast` inside my react project but I do not see any contrast adjusting function in TFJS.